# Error "...FQTV DATA NOT SUPPORTED.." to Add Frequent Flyer Using PassengerDetailsRQ

Tags: sabre

I would like to add a frequent flyer using PassengerDetails as follow...

```
<PassengerDetailsRQ xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.0.0">
  <PostProcessing RedisplayReservation="true" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10">
    <EndTransactionRQ>
      <EndTransaction Ind="true" />
      <Source ReceivedFrom="AddingFF" />
    </EndTransactionRQ>
  </PostProcessing>
  <PreProcessing xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10">
    <UniqueID ID="XXXXXX" />
  </PreProcessing>
  <SpecialReqDetails xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" />
  <TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10">
    <CustomerInfo>
      <CustLoyalty MembershipID="123456789" NameNumber="1.1" ProgramID="AV" SegmentNumber="1" />
    </CustomerInfo>
  </TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
</PassengerDetailsRQ>
```

But in the response, I received this error

> .SEGMENT SPECIFIC FQTV DATA NOT SUPPORTED FOR THESE AIRLINES

However, I looked the list (command PT*) and it has the airline AV.
So, I didn't understand that error.
Does anybody got this error?

And other question, what does FQTV mean?

Comment: What airline do you have booked in the reservation? Sounds like it is not AV - perhaps the target airline does not accept GDS SSRs for FQTV programs?

Answer (score 0):

Without the complete information is hard to give a complete response, for which you might want to check with the helpdesk.

Anyway, you might need to put the carrier the person is actually traveling by adding `TravelingCarrierCode="YY"`

```
<CustLoyalty MembershipID="123456789" NameNumber="1.1" ProgramID="AV" SegmentNumber="1" TravelingCarrierCode="YY"/>
```

Regarding your FQTV question, it means **F**re**q**uent **T**ra**v**eler

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved.

In this case, the problem was the segment number. 
I can't send it for any cias.
To solve my problem I just needed to send the request without the segment number attribute.

To know if it is necessary to send the segment number or not just execute the following command PT*{cia} (PT*AV).

Example to cia AV:

```
PT*AV
FQTV PARTICIPATING AIRLINE EXCHANGE/PARTNERSHIP AGREEMENTS
----------------------------------------------------------
 USE. FF(OC)(FF NUMBER)/(RC)-N.N TO TRANSMIT FLIGHT INFO
         OC-OWNING       RC-RECEIVING
            CARRIER         CARRIER

         /*/ SEGMENT SPECIFIC ALLOWED

 AV-134 AVIANCA
        ACCEPTS FF ACCOUNT NUMBERS IN THE PROGRAMS LISTED
        AC  AI  AM  AV  A3* BR  CA  CM  ET* IB* LH  LR* NH*
        NZ* OS  OZ  SA* SK  SQ* TA* TG* TK* TP  UA
```